# If I have that $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ are from a $Pois(\lambda)$ distribution, why is $\bar{Y} \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\bar{Y}}{n}}$ a $95$% CI?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval

Suppose I have that $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ are from a $Pois(\lambda)$ distribution, I am told that $\bar{Y} \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\bar{Y}}{n}}$ a $95$% CI for $\lambda$.

However, I am not clear why. I know that for $n$ large, $\bar{Y} \sim N\left(\lambda, \frac{\lambda}{n}\right)$ approximately. However, how does this fact turn into the above? Can someone tell me where my derivations are incorrect below?:

$$
0.95 = P\left(-1.96 \leq \frac{\bar{Y}-\lambda}{\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{n}}} \leq 1.96\right) = P\left(\bar{Y}-1.96\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{n}} \leq \lambda \leq \bar{Y}+1.96\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{n}}\right)
$$

However, at this point I CANNOT move the $\lambda$'s into the middle as it is not linear. Ideally, I would like $\lambda$ right in the middle, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Many introductory textbooks approximate $\lambda$ in the denominator by the sample estimate $\bar Y$.  Then you end up with the above interval.  However, you _can_ solve the quadratic double inequality with respect to $\lambda$.  This leads to an asymmetric interval with coverage closer to the nominal level.

Comment: You should also look at this thread http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122836/poisson-confidence-interval-using-the-pivotal-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the poisson distribution, the variance equals the expectation, so the variance can be estimated by $\bar{Y}$.  Then the above interval follows by a normal approximation. But better intervals can be constructed, one mentioned by @Jarle Tufto in a comment. You can also see [Poisson confidence interval using the pivotal method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122836/poisson-confidence-interval-using-the-pivotal-method),   [Confidence interval for a small number of iid Poisson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56333/confidence-interval-for-a-small-number-of-iid-poisson)